# Retrieve group/muc chat history using smack in android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, multiuserchat

I am using the **Smack 4.3.4** android library. I am facing issues while fetching the chat history of a particular group using the below code. But its return 0 However, There are many messages which I can see using another client web.

```
private fun initGroupChatRoom(){
       val mucEnterConfiguration = multiUserChat?.getEnterConfigurationBuilder(nickname)!!
           .requestNoHistory()
           .build()

       try {
           if (!multiUserChat!!.isJoined) {
               multiUserChat?.join(mucEnterConfiguration)
           }
       }catch (e: Exception){
           Log.e("GrpChatAct","Join Error: "+e.toString())
       }

       multiUserChat?.addMessageListener(incomingMessageListener)
   }

private fun chatHistory(){
       CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
           var mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(multiUserChat)

           var result =  async {
               mamManager.enableMamForAllMessages()
               mamManager.queryMostRecentPage(jId, 70)
           }.await()
        Log.e("GrpChatAct","Total Messages: "+result.messageCount)
     }
}
```

I also tried with below changes in MamManager:

```
var mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection)
```

Where **mConnection** is **smack connection** object.

But still, I am getting 0 messages in the result.

I followed code from [this](https://medium.com/@codetoart/how-to-implement-multi-user-chat-group-chat-in-android-using-smack-library-c616bc373ef1) reference.

Is there anything I miss in the code or mistakes I made?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that a MAM archive is being maintained. On Openfire, you need to have installed the Monitoring plugin for that. Also, the Monitoring plugin must be configured to store messages (which it does not do by default).

Comment: I also tried same and not getting past messages. It is working fine for one to one chat

Comment: @MihirPatel I solved it with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

**fetching the chat history of a particular group using the below code**

val multiUserChatManager =
MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(XmppChatConnection.instance?.connection)

```
 val multiUserChat = multiUserChatManager?.getMultiUserChat(mucJid)
                    val mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(multiUserChat)
                    val mamQueryArgs = MamManager.MamQueryArgs.builder()
                            .limitResultsSince(endDate)
                            .setResultPageSize(1000000000)
                            .queryLastPage()
                            .build()
                    val mamQuery = mamManager.queryArchive(mamQueryArgs)
                    val messageList = mamQuery.messages
```